# What is the attempt to text file thing that for that figuring sections?

Tags: java

NEW EDIT**

I am attempting to parse the following lines contained in a file called stuff.make.

```
[Utilize 1x Bolt to Helicopter until 10s]
[Utilize Boat until 5s]
[Utilize 7x Bolt to Helicopter until 2s]
[Utilize 4x Wrench to Tank until 3s]
```

EDITED** Want output(Output I am aiming for):

```
1
Bolt
Helicopter
10
Boat
5
7
Bolt
Helicopter
2
4
Wrench
Tank
3
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first regex you missed the `\s` after `Silver:`

In the second regex you missed the `x` after `(\\d*)`

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\[(Silver):\\s(\\d+)\\]");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\[Utilize (\\d*)x (\\w*)");
// I used * so that in the case of line 3, where a word comes after 'Utilize'
// rather than number, * doesn't have to match so would ignore \\d* and only
// take into account the \\w* to print out 'Boat'

Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(list[i]);
Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(list[i]);

while(m1.find()){
    System.out.println(m1.group(1));// Prints out Silver
    System.out.println(m1.group(2));// Prints out 9
}
while(m2.find()){
    System.out.println(m2.group(1)); //Should print 2 then in next line be ignored
    System.out.println(m2.group(2)); //Should print Bolt then next line Boat
}
```

**EDIT**

The new regex you added the `?` only applies to the previous character. So for this to work properly you need to group the `to` together to make the entire word optional. To simplify you're regex a bit, I tossed the `\s` into the group.

```
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("(?:to\\s)?(\\w*)\\suntil\\s(\\d+)s\\]");
```

**EDIT**

In the comments, I'm being asked why I'm using `\s` versus a space. I figure it'll be easier for me to explain in the answer. Simply put, I prefer to use `\s` unless I have a reason not too. The `\s` matches on any white space character, which makes a space, tab, or other white space characters match the regex. With this, realize the `\s` will make you're Regex slightly more flexible, but comes at the cost of not knowing the exact character that was matched. Also be aware that different regex engines can implement the `\s` differently, which is why I said 'other white space characters' earlier.

So when would you use a space over the `\s` syntax?

When you don't want the regex to match if there's any character other than a space. This can be valid in some cases, but it's truly depends on the requirements for the regex. Maybe it's a critical piece of code, and you don't want to touch anything that matches what you expect exactly.

All of this isn't to say you can't prefer a space over `\s`. Just understand the difference, so you can choose wisely.

Here's a [short tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) on the `\s` character.

**EDIT**

The [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class cannot be used the way you're trying to use it within the while loop. Here's how you need to reorganize that section

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    s = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Notice it's checking to make sure there's another line available before reading the line.

**EDIT**

Here's my test program, input file, and output. I've modified this to match the output you've modified the question too. The major change here is I modified the code to only need a single Regex. You could have done this with two, but knowing what you're trying to accomplish I think this is a cleaner way to work with it. The regex is still pretty simple. It's just a merge between the two you had, and I made a couple of the capturing groups optional to handle the different text.

The other things I did was clean up the code and fixed you're bugs. Please take the time to look at the changes and understand them. The major things were I reorganized the `try/catch` block and added a `finally` block. So it'd be worth while for you to sit down and read about proper resource handling and try catches.

The link below will show the regex and it gives you a nice breakdown of everything. Should be helpful for you understanding the regex I wrote.

[Regex](http://regex101.com/r/hL8dB9/1)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Parser("C:\\Users\\Nathan.DOZIERINC\\Downloads\\test.txt");
}

public static void Parser(String Path) //Got the path of stuff.make
{
    File f = new File(Path);
    Scanner scan = null;
    //Notice I combined the two try/catches you had and included a finally. The way you were
    //doing this would have caused issues when the file was not found. So please read up on using try/catch/finally.
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(f);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine();

            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(?:(?<count>\\d+)x)?\\s(?<type>[\\w]+)(?:\\sto\\s(?<secondType>\\w+))?\\suntil\\s(?<seconds>\\d+)s\\]");
            Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s);

            while (m1.find()) {
                String count = m1.group("count");
                String type = m1.group("type");
                String secondType = m1.group("secondType");
                String seconds = m1.group("seconds");

                //If count is null, that means the regex didn't find this OPTIONAL group
                if (count != null)
                    System.out.println(count);

                //I'm not checking for null on type simply because the regex will fail
                // if this group is not found.
                System.out.println(type);

                //If secondType is null, that means the regex didn't find this OPTIONAL group
                if (secondType != null)
                    System.out.println(secondType);

                //I'm not checking for null on type simply because the regex will fail
                // if this group is not found.
                System.out.println(seconds);
                System.out.println("---");
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Here it prints out the error: Error while reading file line by line: For input string:         ""
        System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        //ALWAYS clean up your resources, you were not doing this in the original
        if (scan != null) {
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of test.txt

```
[Utilize 1x Bolt to Helicopter until 10s]
[Utilize Boat until 5s]
[Utilize 7x Bolt to Helicopter until 2s]
[Utilize 4x Wrench to Tank until 3s]
```

And the output I'm receiving

```
1
Bolt
Helicopter
10
---
Boat
5
---
7
Bolt
Helicopter
2
---
4
Wrench
Tank
3
---
```

Comment: Appreciate for checking. while((s2 = scan.hasNextLine()) != null){ s2 = scan.nextLine(); }; Is this correct?

Comment: @OM: Remove the `!= null` and it should be correct. The `hasNextLine()` function returns a boolean.

Comment: Sorry but I accidentally put s2. There was no s2 to begin with. Could you check if the correction you suggested is still the answer to the problem?

Comment: @OM: It's updated, but honestly it's simple as just renaming `s2` to the variable you do have. I'm assuming it's `s`, so just replace `s2` with `s`.

Comment: Commented the original post with the correction, and tried it out but I am still getting the same error 'Error while reading file line by line: For input string: " " '

Comment: @OM: Check edit, there's nothing wrong with the code itself. Try copying and pasting the code, AND use the test input file I provide. Just fyi, you can print the stacktrace so you can see the line number to the piece of code that's causing the problem... which would be helpful. If you're receiving the error it's because you're source code does not match what you're posting or there's an edge case in you're input file that's causing an issue.

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you Nathan!! But the only problem now is that it prints out Boat two times. Why is it doing that?

Comment: @OM: Both regexes will pick up the Boat. Refer to the links, they'll show the problem. [First Regex](http://regex101.com/r/aP9nA9/1), [Second Regex](http://regex101.com/r/nE7iX8/1). Without knowing the purpose of the Regexes/program, I can't really suggest any changes. However, assuming you just don't want the regexes to repeat names, you could change the second regex to [this](http://regex101.com/r/nE7iX8/2). Notice the missing `?` on the first group. (But you'll miss the seconds on boat.) I just don't know what you're after to be able to help.

Comment: Understood and I edited the original post with the output I am aiming for. I still can't seem to manage to output it so with the suggestion you provided. What do you think needs to be fixed?

Comment: @OM: I've updated the last section of my answer to show you how I would have handled this; it should give you a good understanding of everything. I went through and tried to fix the problems I seen (ie merged the `try/catch`, added `finally` block, and merged the regexes into a single regex.) Hopefully this will get you on track, and I tried to explain everything in the answer/comments. Good Luck.